# Textbox draggable in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I design a draggable textbox in my HTML page. i have written below statement for draggable textbox. but its not working. Can anybody tell me where i am wrong?

Here is my Code.

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id='Test' style="position:relative"/>
```

**jquery :**

```
$("#Test").draggable({  scroll: false }).resizable();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkh1m940/)**

**EDIT :**

One More thing draggable  not working When i add re sizable

```
 $("#Test").draggable({cancel:''});
 $("#Test").resizable();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkh1m940/8/)**